# TF: Loop through map with lookup and set variable accordingly

Tags: terraform, hcl

I have a map with some environment ID's as the key, then keywords as the values in a list.

```
variable "environments" {
  type    = map(list(string))
  default = {
    "env-one" = ["dev", "test", "stage", "staging"],
    "env-two" = ["prod", "production", "live"]
  }
}
```

I'm looking to use this to set the environment name based on the value of `var.context["stage"]`.

So, if `var.context["stage"]` is equal to `staging` the value of `environment` will be `dev`

I was initially thinking to use `lookup()`, something like;

```
environment = "${lookup(var.environments, var.context["stage"])}"
```

However, I realise that's looking up the wrong way (finding the value as opposed to the key), and also it won't work as part of a map. So presumably I need to look through the map and run the lookup (albeit) backwards(?) on each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to restructure the type into `map(string)`. Then it would follow that the value would be:

```
{
  "dev"        = "env-one",
  "test"       = "env-one",
  "stage"      = "env-one",
  "staging"    = "env-one",
  "prod"       = "env-two",
  "production" = "env-two",
  "live"       = "env-two"
}
```

You could also modify this to be `map(object)` to contain more information. Based on the usage described in the question, this would actually make more sense to be a `local`. If you were to place this data into a `locals` block named `environments`, then the key-value pair could be accessed (according to the question) like `local.environments[var.context["stage"]]`.